# Using PHP scripts in Vue

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, axios

I have Vue app that has to use some PHP scripts. If I place them on server everything works fine and I am able to make Axios request like:

```
this.$http
  .post("http://my-domain.com/scripts/news.php", {
    action: "getAll"
  })
```

Still, I would like to have those scripts in my local development environment and use them like this:

```
this.$http
  .post("/scripts/news.php", {
    action: "getAll"
  })
```

with scripts placed in `public/scripts`. When tried with PHP dev server or Apache I could only use them when requesting `http://localhost/scripts/news.php` and proxing PHP server with `vue.config.js`, but it is not useful since I would need to change that when switching to production.

How to configrue it properly?

Comment: Maybe the devServer.proxy helps you https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting up the base url of axios.

```
import axios from 'axios'
window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
window.axios.defaults.baseURL = (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') ? 'http://my-domain.com/' : ''
```

Comment: Great idea! I have played around with this and it solved my problem! Thank you :)